# IF function in Power Query issue

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have this table in Power Query:

[image]

I want to do a if function :

```
= if[quantitée facturée]=1 = [quantité retournée] = 1 then 1 else 0
```

but I don't understand why every result of the function is "0" even when `quantité facturée` =/ `quantité retournée`

I also tried:

```
= if [quantitée facturée]=1 and [quantité retournée]=1 then 1 else 0

= if [quantitée facturée]=1 or [quantité retournée]=1 then 1 else 0

= if [quantitée facturée] = [quantité retournée] then 1 else 0

= if [quantitée facturée] <> [quantité retournée] then 1 else 0
```

I seek to obtain each time a delivered order has been returned by the customer and count it as a neutral delivery

Here is what I got with the function mentioned above:

[image]

Any ideas?

edit:
M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook()
    EXPBLLT1_Sheet = Source{[Item="EXPBLLT1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"En-têtes promus" = Table.PromoteHeaders(EXPBLLT1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"En-têtes promus",{{"CODART", type text}, {"LIBELL", type text}, {"QLIVRE", Int64.Type}, {"NUMSER", type text}, {"SORPCE_A", type text}, {"CODCLI", type text}, {"RAISOC", type text}, {"NUMDOC", type text}, {"CODOBJ", type text}, {"CHRONO", Int64.Type}, {"ENTPCE", type text}, {"ENTMVT", type text}, {"SORPCE_B", type text}, {"SORMVT", type text}, {"DATEMV", type date}, {"SORPMR", type text}, {"BL", type text}, {"NUM_CDE", type text}, {"CHIRURGIEN", type text}, {"CODREP", type text}, {"PATIENT", type text}, {"DATE_INTER", type date}, {"ENTDAT", type date}, {"SORDAT", type date}, {"EMPDES", type text}, {"LIBFOU", type text}, {"BL 2", Int64.Type}, {"Compteur BL", Int64.Type}, {"année.mois inter", type date}, {"Mouvement", type text}}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée" = Table.AddColumn(#"Type modifié", "Quantité facturée", each [SORMVT]="700"),
    #"Type modifié1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée",{{"Quantité facturée", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Type modifié1", "Quantitée retournée", each [ENTMVT]="610"),
    #"Type modifié2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée1",{{"Quantitée retournée", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Lignes filtrées" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié2", each true),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Lignes filtrées", "Quantité retournée", each [SORMVT]="610"),
    #"Type modifié3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée2",{{"Quantité retournée", type number}, {"Quantitée retournée", type text}}),
    #"Colonnes supprimées" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Type modifié3",{"Quantité facturée", "Quantitée retournée", "Quantité retournée"}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées", "quantitée facturée", each [SORMVT]="700"),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personnalisée ajoutée3", "quantitée livrée", each [ENTMVT]="610"),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personnalisée ajoutée4", "quantité retournée", each [SORMVT]="610"),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personnalisée ajoutée5", "Livraison blanche", each if [quantitée livrée] = [quantité retournée] then 1 else 0),
    #"Type modifié4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée6",{{"Livraison blanche", type text}}),
    #"Colonnes supprimées1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Type modifié4",{"Livraison blanche"}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées1", "Livraison blanche", each if [ENTMVT]="710" = [SORMVT]="700" then 1 else 0),
    #"Type modifié5" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée7",{{"Livraison blanche", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Lignes filtrées2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié5", each true),
    #"Colonnes supprimées2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Lignes filtrées2",{"Livraison blanche"}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée8" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées2", "Livraisons blanches", each if [ENTMVT]="610" = [SORMVT]="700" then 1 else 0),
    #"Lignes filtrées1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Personnalisée ajoutée8", each true),
    #"Colonnes supprimées3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Lignes filtrées1",{"Livraisons blanches"}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée10" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées3", "Livraisons blanches", each if [quantitée livrée]="TRUE" = [quantité retournée]="TRUE" then 1 else 0),
    #"Type modifié6" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée10",{{"quantitée facturée", Int64.Type}, {"quantitée livrée", Int64.Type}, {"quantité retournée", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Colonnes supprimées4" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Type modifié6",{"Livraisons blanches"}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée9" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées4", "Livraisons blanches", each if [quantitée livrée]=1 = [quantité retournée]=1 then "1" else "0"),
    #"Colonnes supprimées5" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Personnalisée ajoutée9",{"Livraisons blanches"}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée11" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées5", "Livraisons blanches", each if[quantitée livrée]=1 =[quantité retournée]=1 then 1 else 5),
    #"Colonnes supprimées6" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Personnalisée ajoutée11",{"Livraisons blanches"}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée12" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées6", "Livraisons blanches )", each if[quantitée facturée]=1 = [quantité retournée] = 1 then 1 else 0),
    #"Type modifié7" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée12",{{"Livraisons blanches )", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Lignes filtrées3" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié7", each true),
    #"Colonnes supprimées7" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Lignes filtrées3",{"Livraisons blanches )"}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée13" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées7", "Livraisons blanches", each if [quantitée facturée]=1 and [quantité retournée]=1 then 1 else 0),
    #"Colonnes supprimées8" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Personnalisée ajoutée13",{"Livraisons blanches"}),
    #"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées8", "Livraisons blanches", each if [quantitée livrée] = 0 then 0 else if [quantitée livrée] = [quantité retournée] then 1 else 0),
    #"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée", "quantité retournée test", each if [SORMVT] = "610" then 1 else 0),
    #"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée1", "quantité facturée test", each if [SORMVT] = "700" then 1 else 0),
    #"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée2", "quantitée livrée test", each if [ENTMVT] = "610" then 1 else 0),
    #"Colonnes supprimées9" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée3",{"quantitée facturée", "quantitée livrée", "quantité retournée"}),
    #"Colonnes renommées" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Colonnes supprimées9",{{"quantité retournée test", "quantité retournée"}, {"quantité facturée test", "quantité facturée"}, {"quantitée livrée test", "quantitée livrée"}}),
    #"Colonnes permutées" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Colonnes renommées",{"CODART", "LIBELL", "QLIVRE", "NUMSER", "SORPCE_A", "CODCLI", "RAISOC", "NUMDOC", "CODOBJ", "CHRONO", "ENTPCE", "ENTMVT", "SORPCE_B", "SORMVT", "DATEMV", "SORPMR", "BL", "NUM_CDE", "CHIRURGIEN", "CODREP", "PATIENT", "DATE_INTER", "ENTDAT", "SORDAT", "EMPDES", "LIBFOU", "BL 2", "Compteur BL", "année.mois inter", "Mouvement", "quantitée livrée", "quantité retournée", "quantité facturée", "Livraisons blanches"}),
    #"Colonnes supprimées10" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Colonnes permutées",{"Livraisons blanches"}),
    #"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées10", "Livraisons blanches", each if [quantitée livrée] = 0 then 0 else if [quantitée livrée] = [quantité retournée] then 1 else 0),
    #"Type modifié9" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Colonne conditionnelle ajoutée4",{{"quantitée livrée", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Lignes filtrées5" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié9", each true),
    #"Type modifié10" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Lignes filtrées5",{{"quantité facturée", Int64.Type}, {"quantité retournée", Int64.Type}, {"Livraisons blanches", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Lignes filtrées4" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié10", each true),
    #"Type modifié8" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Lignes filtrées4",{{"Livraisons blanches", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Duplication de la colonne" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Type modifié8", "DATEMV", "DATEMV - Copier"),
    #"Fractionner la colonne par délimiteur" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplication de la colonne", {{"DATEMV - Copier", type text}}, "fr-FR"), "DATEMV - Copier", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"/"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"DATEMV - Copier.1", "DATEMV - Copier.2"}),
    #"Type modifié11" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Fractionner la colonne par délimiteur",{{"DATEMV - Copier.1", type date}, {"DATEMV - Copier.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Colonnes supprimées11" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Type modifié11",{"DATEMV - Copier.1"}),
    #"Colonnes renommées1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Colonnes supprimées11",{{"DATEMV - Copier.2", "Année"}}),
    #"Type modifié12" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Colonnes renommées1",{{"Année", type text}})
in
    #"Type modifié12"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to tell what you are looking for but potential versions for a custom column formula are

= if [quantitée facturée]=1 and [quantité retournée]=1 then 1 else 0

= if [quantitée facturée]=1 or [quantité retournée]=1 then 1 else 0

= if [quantitée facturée] = [quantité retournée] then 1 else 0

= if [quantitée facturée] <> [quantité retournée] then 1 else 0

Comment: i got the same result : 0 every time even when two columns have a 1, really don't understand why

Comment: I seek to obtain each time a delivered order has been returned by the customer and count it as a neutral delivery

Comment: edit your question and paste in your code

Comment: i did, hope it will be usefull, i really don't get it why i only have zero as result

Comment: please post entire code

Comment: there is no other M code, columns were extracted from a CSV, its literrally like in the screen that i posted

Comment: @YannP I suspect you are just pasting in the formula from the Add Column dialog box. When we mention `M Code`, what you need to do is navigate to `Home=>Query=>Advanced Editor`. The `Advanced Editor` window will open with **ALL** of the generated code.  Copy/Paste the contents of **that** window into your question

Comment: Sorry i didnt know yet about this function, i'm going to edit my question with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why `if [quantitée facturée]=1 or [quantité retournée]=1 then 1 else 0` doesn't work.  I would be curious to see the entire generated M code from the Advanced Editor.

However, you could try using the [Add Conditional Column](https://radacad.com/conditional-column-in-power-bi-using-power-query-you-can-do-anything) dialog.  This will allow you to use the GUI to setup your column logic, and will generate M code that looks something like this:

```
if [quantitée facturée] = 1 then 1 else if [quantité retournée] = 1 then 1 else 0
```

Comment: i just did it and it worked with the conditionnal Column, which basically was the same result that i did before. 

there was no other M code, columns were extracted from a CSV
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check your codes

Basically you add the column `Livraison blanche` in #"Personnalisée ajoutée6" then removed it, then add it again #"Personnalisée ajoutée7", then removed again.

#"Personnalisée ajoutée7" could be the reason why all are 0

```
#"Personnalisée ajoutée6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personnalisée ajoutée5", "Livraison blanche", each if [quantitée livrée] = [quantité retournée] then 1 else 0),
#"Type modifié4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée6",{{"Livraison blanche", type text}}),
#"Colonnes supprimées1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Type modifié4",{"Livraison blanche"}),
#"Personnalisée ajoutée7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes supprimées1", "Livraison blanche", each if [ENTMVT]="710" = [SORMVT]="700" then 1 else 0),
#"Type modifié5" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée7",{{"Livraison blanche", Int64.Type}}),
#"Lignes filtrées2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié5", each true),
#"Colonnes supprimées2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Lignes filtrées2",{"Livraison blanche"}),
```

Learn to write tidy steps, even in PQ, it helps.

Comment: You probably right i should deleted previous steps before setting up a new one. I'm still currently learning PQ. Anyways the function is now running correctly with "Conditional Column", i still don't know why considering the fact the code is the same i did before, but its works...